# Show two editText views and a button when softKeyboard opens

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to scroll so that the two editText views and the button are all shown when the keyboard opens up. I have already tried adding softInputMode to the xml (I set it to adjustResize). I am now completely lost on how to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

[Before the Keyboard shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JPtb.png)

[When the keyboard opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBIdQ.png)

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUyRM.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post your xml codes

Comment: Try putting the EditText and Button inside of a NestedScrollView